What is this component ? NEB EM600

It came out of an EVSE. It's open circuit or at least very high resistance.

It looks like a gas discharge tube (a type of surge suppressor) but I'm not seeing anything online with those markings. It's a fairly precise spark gap so high impedance would make sense.

Thanks for that info. I have also searched for ages on the internet but not found a single thing about those markings. What you say makes perfect sense as it was connected between a pair of MOVs (which I believe are also used for surge protection) and Earth. One of the MOVs was burnt but the surge current would have to go through this gas tube thing to get to earth so does it mean it is dead as it has probably been "used" and its high resistance would mean no path to earth or is it a bit like the MOVs in that it  breaks down at a higher voltage than my meter puts out ?

It is similar to a MOV in that it remains high-resistance until a certain voltage whereupon it switches into a low-resistance state. This can occur repeatedly depending on the amount of surge current. Your device appears to be rated for a break over voltage of 600V.

It's a gas discharge tube, probably a compatible with Epcos/TDK EM600, which has a 600V spark-over voltage.


As you can see from the specs, they're designed for very occasional use (such as during a rare thunderstorm), even more so than their crude amorphous semiconductor cousins the Metal Oxide Varistor (MOV). Unlike the latter, I suspect they'll tend to fail more-or-less open.
Whoever removed that part from the PCB seriously damaged the latter. The sad remnants of the plated-through-hole are still clinging to the lead.

Right, thanks for the info. Would you say it's had it then ? Is there a way to test definitively with just a multimeter ?

You'd need at least a high-voltage (480VDC to  750VDC) adjustable source and a power resistor to test it properly (preferably something more like a Tektronix 576 Curve Tracer).  But if it measures open and looks okay,  it's "probably" okay.

If it turns out to be "dead" it's probably not the reason why the EVSE is throwing an "earth leakage" error, I'm guessing some damage must have been done elsewhere.
